# How to ignore E_DEPRECATED errors in PHP?

Tags: php, error-handling, error-reporting

I have an old Wordpress plugin that I'm still using for legacy and have no intention to update it. This plugin creates a few minor deprecated errors that show up in my Wordpress dashboard, and I would like to remove them.

I added this line of code to the plugin code:

```
error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED );
```

This seems to work, meaning that I don't see the deprecated error messages in the dashboard anymore; however, the errors still show up in my error log file whenever I make a request to my Wordpress site, so I guess the errors are still reported?

I log errors hooking into Wordpress' default shutdown process:

```
add_action( "shutdown", "log_fatal_errors" );

function log_fatal_errors() {
   
   $e = error_get_last(); 
   
   if( ! empty($e) ) {
      $Logger = get_logger(); // This returns my logger class, which consists of a series of different Monolog loggers
      $Logger->app->critical( $e["message"] );
   }
   
}
```

Comment: Disable the plugin or find an alternative. That'll stop the errors. The plugin will cease to function in the future anyways.

Comment: You could ignore the `type`. https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.error-get-last.php
F.e. `E_DEPRECATED` has the value `8192`. But as @InvictusMKS said - the function will be disabled ... and then the deprecated becomes a fatal error.

Comment: Note: if you choose to ignore the deprecated (because you get massive e-msgs spammed) then you SHOULD at least ignore only this specific warnings. So you wont miss new ones. A simple check if `type` is a deprecated one and `strpos(message, 'part of the the message to ignore') !== false` would do the job.

Comment: What do you mean the function will be disabled? By who?

Comment: You can also just fix the plugin. If the plugin is old, that implies it isn't getting updated so there should be no harm.

Comment: To suppress notices as well:
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED

Comment: @grazianodev "By who?" --by the next PHP version (that you or your host installs in the future)

Comment: @cottton Then I guess I'll just fix the plugin, it is only a couple of functions at the core of the issue. Thank you.

Comment: `the function will be disabled? By who?`...do you understand what "deprecated" means? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation#Software ... _"Deprecated status may also indicate the feature will be removed in the future. Features are deprecated, rather than immediately removed, to provide backward compatibility and to give programmers time to bring affected code into compliance with the new standard"_